# Mongoose adding values to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I add a User to the School's admins field?

School Schema:

```
const School = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    grades_primary: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Grade' }],
    grades_secondary: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Grade' }],
    admins: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
})
```

User Schema

```
const User = new Schema({
    complete_name: { type: String, required: true, },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    nombre_de_usuario: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
})
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
const saved_user = await user.save()

created_school.admins.push(saved_user)

await created_school.save()
```

Comment: can you add the whole function please ?

Answer (score 0):

use $push

```
const saved_user = await user.save()

 try {
    const created_school= await School.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: '1' }, { $push: { admins: saved_user } })
   // ....
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
  }
```